# How does one use a transistor connected in either series or parallel with the load in a linear regulated power supply?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, 12v, linear-regulator

Let's say using a transformer and a rectifier to bring the voltage supply to roughly 18 DC (little voltage ripple which solved by using polarised capacitors) and I use a LM7812 regulator to bring down the capactior to 12V DC

How would I incoparted a high power transistor connected in either series/parallel with the load in a linear regulated power supply?

Edit: I want to be able to design a linear regulated power supply but with a bjt near the load, I'm on the basics of understanding electrical engineering and it's a requirement for my project however I'm not sure how to incorporate the transistor onto the linear regulated power supply. since the purpose of a transistor is to amplifer the current, would that impact the amount of voltage towards the end? My goal is to design a LRPS with a transistor. therefore I want to accomplish a goal to have such design to be able to supply electrical power to a load

Comment: "*How would I incoparted a high power transistor connected in either series/parallel with the load in a linear regulated power supply?*" To do what exactly? [Edit] your question rather than elaborate in the comments. That way all the information will be in one place.

Comment: Given the edit, I'd like to ask yet another question to clarify further. Are you supposed to "wrap" a transistor around an LM7812 in order to increase the regulated voltage's "current compliance?" If so, I think you can find an example schematic right on the datasheet for the LM7812. But I really can't tell what you want, just yet. So I'm uncertain.

Comment: What's an LRPS? Your question is still rather confused. Are you trying to make a variable load using this transistor?

Comment: Yeah, I'm suppose to have a transistor near the LM7812 as a support boost for the regulation

Comment: Transistor: Linear Regulated Power Supply. no I'm not trying to make a variable load, I want my load to hold only 12V D.C. and have a transistor near the load

Comment: One cannot understand your requirements without Current or load Impedance specs!

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds confusing

Comment: Can you state your project specification to clarify all of this? "*Design a power supply with a linear regulator and bypass transistor to regulate voltage to XX volts and supply a maximum current of YY amperes.*" or similar. Have you read the 78xx datasheets to look at how this problem is solved? Most of them have sample circuits for what you want.

Comment: It sounds as if you had a thermal problem or a current limit problem which is unspecified so far.

Comment: "Design a power supply with a linear regulator and bypass transistor to regulate voltage to 12 volts and supply a maximum current of 5 amperes."

Comment: My issue is the confusion with the used with a transistor after the application of the LM7812 regulator. My goal is to only design it, not to construct it, And I'm currently using a NI Mulitsim 14.2 to design it

Comment: There are such suggested circuits in some of the 78xx datasheets. Both with and without SC protection.

Comment: See [ST's 7812 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf) and find Figures 14 and 15.

Comment: Thank you a lot guys!!! Now I can understand the application, I'm a novice here in this field so I appericiate a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question relates to two types of regulator circuits - 'Series' and 'Shunt'.

In a series regulator circuit the load voltage would be maintained by dropping the excess voltage across the series transistor.

[image]

In a shunt regulator circuit the load voltage and that maintained across the shunt transistor would be one and the same.

[image]

Generally, series and shunt regulators, available in 3 terminal packages, would be adequate for the required load current.

Otherwise additional external transistors would be required.

Answer (score 2):

> "Design a power supply with a linear regulator and bypass transistor to regulate voltage to 12 volts and supply a maximum current of 5 amperes."

The solution is presented in the 78xx series datasheet on page 20.

[image]

> I want to be able to design a linear regulated power supply but with a bjt near the load, ...

No, you want to use a BJT to boost the current handling ability of your voltage regulator.

Comment: Thank you, can I ask something? is the dots between two wires means they are connected?

Comment: Dot's where lines cross or intersect show that they are connected.